# When using Polymerfire and anonymous login, there is no data in firebase-query object

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, polymerfire

I want to create a website using Firebase and Polymer.

There is no need for login (if changed in the Firebase console.firebase.google.com).

Here are the database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

This should be OK for anyone with access to the app.

Yet, when I try to query an element, I get zero results (an empty array).

In short, the code is like this:

```
<firebase-app auth-domain="xyz.firebaseapp.com"
   database-url="https://xyz.firebaseio.com/"
  api-key="AIzaSyB7md4GqkXA-hsEF_CLU3ryHj-xxxxxxxxxx">
</firebase-app>

<firebase-document
  path="/organizers/"
  data="{{noteData}}">
</firebase-document>
  {{noteData}}

<firebase-query
    id="query"

    path="/organizers/"

    data="{{data}}">
</firebase-query>
   {{data}}
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'my-app',

            properties :{
                data: {
                    type:Object,
                    observer: 'dataChanged'
                }
            },
            dataChanged: function (newData, oldData){
                console.log('new data: '+ newData);
                console.log('old data: '+ oldData);

            }

        });
    </script
```

There is data in the database.

I don't get why no data is being retrieved. I don't need the firebase-auth element, since I'm doing an anonymous access off the data, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that with your given code, your data is actually fetched. 
You can remove the

```
<firebase-document>
```

and in your query add a reference to your firebase app object by specifying an app-name.

There isn't a lot of documentation about the app name but I think it functions as a namespace.

Furthermore, there is a problem with how you log the data. Try removing the "new data:" and "old data:" parts from your logging so that the browser dev tools can infer the datatype and display it correctly (as an object/array in your case).

As for your firebase-document, if you want to keep it, the data attribute is bound to "noteData" and not "data"

Comment: He Joey, Thanks. It seems to work just fine with the hints you've provided.

Comment: What's the full solution?